# An object wont let me specified a particular variable - Java

Tags: java

I'm a new learner in java and created my own program to practice and upskill myself. But I have a problem that states [incompatible types: String cannot be converted to Friend] in which I'm having a hard time to figure out why the specific object wont let me specified variable like "friend.name[i]"  Is my logic wrong? How can I fix this? Here's my code:

Main:

```
package Friendprogram;
import Libraries.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class forfunportfolio {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Squad gang = new Squad ("Thunder", 3, 15, 18);
        Friend [] friend = new Friend [gang.maxSlot]; 
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

                   for(int i=0; i<gang.maxSlot; i++){ 
                                                    
                       System.out.printf("Enter Name:");
                       String tmpName = input.next();
                       friend[i] = tmpName; 
                       System.out.println("Enter Age:");
                       int tmpAge = input.nextInt();
                       friend[i] = tmpAge; 
                   }   
                   for(Friend f: friend){
                       gang.Agechecker(f); 
                       gang.newFriend(f); 
                   }
                break;
    }
}
```

Comment: friend[i] =tmpName doesn't work or friend[i].name = tmpName doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of writing `friend[i] = tmpName;` and `friend[i] = tmpAge;`, you need to use the `new` keyword and the constructor for `Friend`.  But you can pass in the variables as arguments, instead of using constants.  That is, you should replace the two problematic lines with this.

```
friend[i] = new Friend(tmpName, tmpAge);
```